# OleDbConnection Connection Error

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, oledbconnection, executenonquery

I wrote these code block:

ConnectDB.getConStr();

```
         string query = "insert into users (memberName,memberSurname,memberEmail,userName,userPassword) values(@mn,@msn,@me,@un,@up)";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( query,ConnectDB.getConStr());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mn", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msn", txtSurname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@me", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@up", txtPassword.Text);

        try
        {
            ConnectDB.getConStr().Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ConnectDB.getConStr().Close();
            ltrMesaj.Text = "Record has been added";
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ltrMesaj.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

But I got an error like this:ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new `instances` of `connection` everytime you are accessing it. so create only one `instance` and use it like this

```
    OleDbConnection connection= ConnectDB.getConStr();
    string query = "insert into users (memberName,memberSurname,memberEmail,userName,userPassword) values(@mn,@msn,@me,@un,@up)";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand( query,connection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mn", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msn", txtSurname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@me", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@up", txtPassword.Text);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            ltrMesaj.Text = "Record has been added";
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ltrMesaj.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Updated my answer and written a code.Take a look and let me know if facing any issue

Comment: I have used `SqlConnection` object as I missed you are using `OleDbCommand` so just change the Sql to OleDb. well I have updated the post.